# Are all $P$-noncomputable sets $P$-random?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability-theory, algorithmic-randomness

$P$ means polynomial complexity.
$S_p$ is class of all $P$_random sets, and $S_{pc}$ is class of all  $P$ incomputable sets, is $S_{pc} \setminus S_p$ empty? If not empty, any example?

what is the result, if we replace $P$ complexity with $NP$?

Moreover, $S$ is class of all random sets, and $S_c$ is class of all incomputable sets,  $S_{c}\setminus S $ is not empty, what is a set in the class $S_{c}\setminus S $,an immune set, productive set, or set of any other kind.

Comment: I do not know what these classes are.  But you could note that $S_{pc} \setminus S_p = \varnothing$ is equivalent to $S_{pc} \subseteq S_p$; that is: every $P$ incomputable set is $P$_random.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your previous question? https://mathoverflow.net/q/348681/1946. My answer there yesterday is the same as Dan's answer here.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins you answer my question, and I tried to rephrase the question and ask them separately, but found you have answered both of them, so I have to merge them, and have forgotten to delete this one which is answered by Dan. I have to keep this one not to let Dan's answer to be deleted with my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the differences are not empty.  As an example, take any noncomputable sequence such that every bit is repeated.  That is, the $(2n)$th bit is the same as the $(2n+1)$th bit, for all $n$.  This will fail to be $P$-random.